# phpmailer class not found in phpmailer 5.2.1

Tags: php, phpmailer

i have a project in php where an old version of phpmailer is used
I am trying to send an email to the customer when they make a purchase from the shop and select the payment method as a bank transfer

this is js code:

```
    function mandamail(){
      var nome = $("#nome").val();
      var cognome = $("#cognome").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inviomailbonifico.php",
        data:"nome="+nome+"&cognome="+cognome+"&email="+email,
        success:function(msg){
          console.log(msg);
          $("#alert").html("controlla la mail per effettuare il bonifico").show();
        }
      })
    }
```

and this is file inviomailbonifico.php

```
require("assets/PHPMailer/PHPMailer_5.2.1/class.phpmailer.php");
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host = "smtp.society.it";
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = 'User';
  $mail->Password = 'passw';

  $mail->CharSet="windows-1251";
  $mail->CharSet="utf-8";

  $mail->Subject = "Coordinate bancarie";

  $messaggio = "";
  
 

 
  $mail->MsgHTML($messaggio);

  $mail->AltBody="L'email è in formato html.";

  $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);

  $mailscuola = "mail send";
  $nomescuola = "name soc";

  $mail->From=$mailscuola;
  $mail->FromName=$nomescuola;
  if(!$mail->Send())
  {   echo "Si è verificato un errore nell'invio dell'email: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;;}
  
  ?>
```

when I click on the button to call the function I get an error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /web/htdocs/www.pierobike.it/home/inviomailbonifico.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>/web/htdocs/www.pierobike.it/home/inviomailbonifico.php</b> on line <b>82</b><br />
```

I looked for many guides and solutions, but none of them solved my problem.

Comment: Did you try `$mail = new \PHPMailer();`?

Comment: FYI, you should rather be requiring the autoloader script, than a specific class file. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable#minimal-installation

Comment: I tried now, unfortunately the problem remains

Comment: What version of PHP is this running in? What is the namespace of the script it's running in?

Comment: PHP Version 7.4 , the script is in root site, and phpmailer is in assets(inside in root)

Comment: the strange thing is that in other parts of the site phpmailer works correctly

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If this works in other parts of your application, what's the difference?

Comment: i can't find the problem, i tried to move the file to different folders, i changed the namespaces, there is no difference in the structure of this piece of code compared to others in the app

Comment: It would help if you posted all the code, not just this snippet. Also, 5.2.1 is very old and contains many known bugs and vulnerabilities, some very serious.

Comment: I managed to solve for the moment but thank you for the suggestion, I will consider an upgrade which apparently is very important